# dateutil.parser.parse() returns a list instead of a datetime object when I use it in a function?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, types

I have this function that has this bit of code in it:

```
result = []
       for date in col:
           result.append(dateutil.parser.parse(date))
```

when i run `dateutil.parser.parse(stringdate)` alone, it returns a datetime object, but in the function, the result list is a list of lists with the format   `['1911', '03', '06']` and I can't figure out why

Comment: what's in `col`? can you add a subset of data?

Comment: col is a pandas DataFrame column with strings that represent dates

Comment: can you also add a subset of data? without that we can't really know what is wrong here. if a create a list of date strings and run the above code, it works as expected so the difference in data and some more code if any is what produces the different results.

Comment: also, perhaps you can just use `to_datetime` method without iterating using the loop. `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Comment: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')` worked! I think the problem was caused by some weird strings in the column, thanks!